# Modem/Router combo connected to Router

Tags: router, modem

I want to use a modem/router combo as a modem only and connect it to a router.  If I put the modem/router in bridge mode and connect it to the router (PPPoE), do I still have to disable NAT or other things on the modem/router combo?

Answer (score 0):

Bridge mode directs all traffic from one interface to the other so there is no NATing happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I wasn't sure and didn't want to end up with conflicts.   I  will only disable wifi on the bridged modem/router and use wifi on the PPPoE router.  Thanks again.